# Measuring Latency and throughput of Hyperledger Besu Blockchain?

Tags: performance, ethereum, latency, hyperledger-besu

i want to measure the latency and throuput of a private ethereum Blockchain (hyperledger besu),
is there any solution ?
thank you

i searched on google for a solution, found only articles describing what latency and throuput means, however i want a solution on how to actually capture it and measure it.

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to try Caliper. I think it's the best tool for this operation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).